# How to modify my codes from jquery to js plus what am doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to code the screen in picture. My javascript is poor, hence i am getting bits of information from where i read or see others do.

I am using vuejs. when i run my numbers I want it to come up as addition to the numbers rather than replacing it. When i press 1323 i want to see 12.23.

below is the code i am currently using:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"  />
<template>
  <div class="mt-1">
    <b-row>
      <div class="text-left">
        <b-btn @click="$router.push('/salesgrid')" variant="transparent"
          ><font-awesome-icon size="2x" :icon="['fas', 'arrow-left']"
        /></b-btn>
      </div>
    </b-row>
    <b-card no-body>
      <b-tabs card align="center">
        <b-tab title="Payment" active>
          <b-row>
            <b-col cols="6">
              <b-list-group horizontal="md" class="row rounded flex-fill">
                <b-list-group-item
                  button
                  class="col-5 rounded border mr-2 shadow"
                  variant="info"
                  cols="1"
                >
                  <div class="text-center"><b>SHOW TENDERS</b></div>
                </b-list-group-item>
              </b-list-group>
            </b-col>
            <b-col class="text-right">
              <b-list-group horizontal="md" class="row rounded flex-fill">
                <b-list-group-item
                  button
                  class="col-5 rounded border mr-2 shadow"
                  variant="info"
                  cols="1"
                >
                  <div class="text-center"><b>SPLIT BY COVERS</b></div>
                </b-list-group-item>
                <b-list-group-item
                  button
                  class="col-5 rounded border mr-2 shadow"
                  variant="info"
                  cols="1"
                >
                  <div class="text-center"><b>SPLIT BY ITEM</b></div>
                </b-list-group-item>
              </b-list-group>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
          <b-row class="mt-4 mb-4">
            <b-col class="bg-light border-right shadow" cols="10" md="4">
              <div class="mt-2">AMOUNT DUE</div>
              <div><h3>0.00</h3></div>
              <div class="mt-3">BASKET DISCOUNT</div>
              <div><h4>0.00</h4></div>
              <div class="mt-3">CUSTOMER DISCOUNT</div>
              <div><h4>0.00</h4></div>
              <div class="mt-3">CUSTOMER POINT SPEND</div>
              <div><h4>0.00</h4></div>
            </b-col>
            <b-col>
              <b-row>
                <b-col
                  style="font-size: 2.25rem"
                  class="bg-light border shadow text-right ml-3 mb-3"
                  md="11"
                >
                  {{ numFormatted }}
                </b-col>
              </b-row>
              <b-row
                v-for="(row, n) in list"
                :key="`row${n}`"
                class="text-center center row container-fluid mb-2"
              >
                <b-list-group
                  horizontal="md"
                  class="row px-md-6 flex-fill ml-1"
                >
                  <b-list-group-item
                    v-for="(item, key) in row"
                    :key="`item${key}`"
                    button
                    class="col mr-1 ml-1 rounded border shadow"
                    value="{value}"
                  >
                    <template v-if="item.paynum">
                      <div class="text-center">
                        <h4 @click="formatNum(item)">
                          {{ item.paynum }}
                        </h4>
                      </div>
                    </template>
                    <span v-else> {{ item }} </span>
                  </b-list-group-item>
                </b-list-group>
              </b-row>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
          <b-row>
            <b-col cols="8">
              <b-list-group horizontal="md" class="row rounded flex-fill">
                <b-list-group-item
                  button
                  class="col-5 rounded border mr-2 shadow"
                  variant="info"
                  cols="1"
                >
                  <div class="text-center"><b>POINTS [0/0.00]</b></div>
                </b-list-group-item>

                <b-list-group-item
                  button
                  class="col-3 rounded border mr-2 shadow"
                  variant="info"
                  cols="1"
                >
                  <div class="text-center"><b>CASH</b></div>
                </b-list-group-item>

                <b-list-group-item
                  button
                  class="col-3 rounded border mr-2 shadow"
                  variant="info"
                  cols="1"
                >
                  <div class="text-center"><b>CARD</b></div>
                </b-list-group-item>
              </b-list-group>
            </b-col>
            <b-col> </b-col>
          </b-row>
        </b-tab>
        <b-tab title="Discount">
          <b-card-text>Feature Not Yet Available</b-card-text>
        </b-tab>
      </b-tabs>
    </b-card>
  </div>
</template><script type="module">
export default {
  name: "SalesGridPay",
  methods: {
    formatNum(data) {
      let string = ``;
      if (data.type == "number") {
        string = `0.00${data.paynum}`;
      } else string = data.paynum;
      return (this.numFormatted = string);
    },
  },
  created() {},
  data: () => ({
    list: [
      [
        { paynum: "1", type: "number" },
        { paynum: "2", type: "number" },
        { paynum: "3", type: "number" },
        { paynum: "$5", type: "USD" },
      ],
      [
        { paynum: "4", type: "number" },
        { paynum: "5", type: "number" },
        { paynum: "6", type: "number" },
        { paynum: "$10", type: "USD" },
      ],
      [
        { paynum: "7", type: "number" },
        { paynum: "8", type: "number" },
        { paynum: "9", type: "number" },
        { paynum: "$20", type: "USD" },
      ],
      [
        { paynum: ".", type: "number" },
        { paynum: "0", type: "number" },
        { paynum: "X", inconz: "th" },
        { paynum: "$55", type: "USD" },
      ],
    ],
    numFormatted: 0.0,
  }),
};
</script>
```

Comment: Your script needs to be type = module to not give errors in the snippet - also you need to include fontawesome. It seems there are more issues before we have a [mcve]

Comment: Also where is your `var vm = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    template: data.template,
    data: data.content
});`

Comment: @mplungjan I am very new to coding. and I dont understand the document that you said i should read. Think stock needs to modify the code feature to make it a little user friendly for newbie like myself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `formatNum()`, :

```js
if (data.type == "number") {
  string = `0.00${data.paynum}`;
}

//...
this.numFormatted = string
```

That prefixes `"0.00"` to the string value of `data.paynum`, and the result is stored in `string`.

Let's walk through a couple calls of `formatNum()`:

1. Press the **1** button.
2. The `click`-handler (`formatNum()`) receives `{ paynum: "1", type: "number" }` as its `data` argument.
3. `data.type` is `"number"`, so it concatenates `"0.00"` with `data.paynum` (`"1"`), which results in `"0.001"`.
4. Press the **2** button.
5. The `click`-handler (`formatNum()`) receives `{ paynum: "2", type: "number" }` as its `data` argument.
6. `data.type` is `"number"`, so it concatenates `"0.00"` with `data.paynum` (`"2"`), which results in `"0.002"`.

Ignoring the prefix problem for a moment, notice how the function just replaces the last value with the new value from `data.paynum`. It needs to take into account the current value of `this.numFormatted` so that new entries are appended.

#### Here's one way to fix this:

1. Extract only the digits from `this.numFormatted`, ignoring all non-numeric characters (e.g., `"$4.11"` is parsed as `"411"`). We'll use [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [regular expression that matches non-digits (`/[\D]/g`)](https://regex101.com/r/la9UJe/1), and replaces them with an empty string.
2. Append `data.paynum` to that result. If `data.paynum` were "2", appending it to `"411"` would result in `"4112"`.
3. Divide the result by `100` to get a currency amount. Applying to the result above would yield `41.12`. Use [`Number.prototype.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to get only two decimal points.

```js
if (data.type === "number") {
  // If it starts with a '$' (i.e., user pressed a preset),
  // set the value to 0, so we can calculate a new number below...
  if (this.numFormatted[0] === "$") {
    this.numFormatted = '0';
  }

  let numRaw = this.numFormatted.replace(/[\D]/g, ""); // 1️⃣
  numRaw += data.paynum; // 2️⃣
  string = (numRaw / 100).toFixed(2); // 3️⃣
}

//...
this.numFormatted = string;
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-payment-form?file=src/components/SalesGridPay.vue)